# Connect to Server using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I'm developing Xamarin Cross platform application. I'm trying to connect to server (http://test.net/login/clientlogin), I need to send these fields (password = "xyz"; platform = iphone; (useremail) = "test@test.com";) along with the request. So that server will check these parameters and returns XML. But we don't know how to add these fields to the request.

When i open the above string url (http://*****/login/clientlogin) i am getting login screen, with in that we have username, password and platform text fields.

Thanks in advance!!!..

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: Hi Clint Landry, Thanks for quich replay. i don't know how to add these fields(username, password, and domain) to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started presuming you are adding the values as headers in the request:

```
public class TestClient
{

    HttpClient client;

    public TestClient(){
        this.client = new HttpClient ();
    }

    public void AddHeadersAndGet(){
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("username", "whatevertheusernameis");
        this.GetAsync<WhateverObjectTypeYouAreReceiving> ("theurloftheservice");
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string address){
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        response = await client.GetAsync (address);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            try {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                return new T (Serializer.DeserializeObject<T> (responseString),
                    response.StatusCode);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

The key line for you is:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("username", "whatevertheusernameis");
```

Comment: Thanks JrdanMazurke, My issuse is fixed using RestClient. Thanks for replay.